# Resource meterial for development purpose

Tags: development

I had asked this on reddit as well.

1) https://learn.iota.org

2) https://kb.helloiota.com/

3) http://www.tangleblog.com/what-is-iota-what-is-the-tangle/

I will appreciate if anyone could add links to where I can get some sample codes/tutorials that I can run and take it from there. I am working on an idea to create somehting over tangle where I can push some data and retrieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- If you're familiar with Python, you can take a look at iota.lib.py's example: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/tree/master/examples
- Or javascript, you still can find the documentation on GitHub: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/
- For the sake of best experience to test, you may want to build up your own full-node: http://iota.partners/